# R: How to find trios of duplicated values among various columns?

Tags: r

I would like to know if it's possible to subset a data frame based on repeated words along the rows, irrespectively from which column are they located in. Therefore, in a data frame like this:

```
    doc      A                B                C               D
 1 DOC1    apple           coconut            berry           pear 
 2 DOC2    prune            apple            banana           berry
 3 DOC3  coconut           cherry             apple          banana
 4 DOC4    berry           banana             pear            prune
```

The desired subset output would be:

```
    doc      A                B                C               D
 2 DOC2    prune            apple            banana           berry
 4 DOC4    berry           banana             pear            prune
```

As those two documents are the only ones that contain three equal values, although they are not ordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to calculate the cross product of the docs by the fruits, and use the indices of the values that are equal to or greater than three to subset the original data:

```
res <- `diag<-`(crossprod(table(cbind(stack(dat, select = -1)[-2], dat[[1]]))), 0)

dat[which(res >= 3, arr.ind = TRUE)[, 2], ]

  doc     A      B      C     D
2 DOC2 prune  apple banana berry
4 DOC4 berry banana   pear prune
```

Data:

```
dat <- read.table(text ="doc      A                B                C               D
1 DOC1    apple           coconut            berry           pear 
2 DOC2    prune            apple            banana           berry
3 DOC3  coconut           cherry             apple          banana
4 DOC4    berry           banana             pear            prune", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: And in this case, how would you extract the trios that are being repetaded? So to get the following result: 1.- {banana, berry, prune}

Comment: Better to ask a new question so you get fresh eyes on it rather than change the scope of an old one.